# How many Symantec Backup Exec agents do I need?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, backupexec, symantec

I will be deploying Backup Exec 2010 R3 to an environment with multiple Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain Controllers.

Do I need to backup Active Directory off of each DC? If yes, would I need a BE Active Directory Agent license for each DC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you backup the Shadow Copy Components on each DC (and you should) then you're backing up AD. 
You only need to purchase the AD agent if you want to do a granular restore of AD objects.

Answer (score -1):

Because Active Directory Sync's off of the "Primary" or Main Server IMHO There is no need to backup the AD from the other AD Servers.

So, No, an agent for that on the other Server is not needed.

You will still need an agent to back up their files though and obviously other Services if they have any like SQL.

Comment: Thanks, would you know which Operations Master I should backup if the FSMOs are distributed between more than one DC?

Comment: If you have it distributed, you need to back up all of them, for good measure

Comment: There is no "Main" or "Primary" Domain Controller. They are multi-master peers. The FMSO roles make no difference. If a DC that holds them fails, you can just seize them on another using `ntdsutil`

Comment: Sorry, going back to my Windows 2000 Lingo. MarkM is correct. ;) But my point still stands, because all DC's have a copy of AD, there is no point